# Solving Modular Equations in ${Z_{18}}$ Given Inverses...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to solve equations like $5X\bmod 18 = 11$ in ${Z_{18}}$ given their inverses. (The modular multiplicative inverse of 5 being 13 in this case.)

How would I do that?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $5^{-1}$. You will get $5^{-1}\cdot5x= x = 11\cdot5^{-1}  \pmod{18}$

Comment: The inverse of $5$ is not $13$… That said, you just have to multiply both sides by $5^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5\cdot13\not\equiv1\pmod{18}\implies5^{-1}\not\equiv13$

Actually $5\cdot11\equiv1\pmod{18}\iff5^{-1}\equiv?$

Now $5x\equiv11\pmod{18}\implies x\equiv11\cdot5^{-1}=?$

Comment: Ah, of course my mistake. I misread my table of inverses from the previous question. I see the result is 13 coincidentally, thank you.